# Reference string parameter causes Segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, parameters, reference, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

Using GCC Compiler on Code::Blocks, I get an error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Process returned 139 (0x8B)
...
```

After entering the input asked.
Here's my test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string getInput(string &input, string prompt)
{
    cout << prompt;
    getline(cin, input);
}

int main()
{
    string input;
    getInput(input, "What's your name?\n>");
    cout << "Hello " << input << "!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong, is the reference parameter being used incorrectly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `getInput` is declared returning a `string` but has no `return` statement which is undefined behavior. If you change the declaration like so:

```
void getInput(string &input, string prompt)
```

The segmentation fault should go away. Having warnings turned on would have helped you find this problem, using `gcc -W -Wall -pedantic` I receive the following warning with your original code:

```
warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
```

Comment: Silly me... It used to return a string, then I changed it to use an out parameter and forgot to change the return value... Thanks, it's hard to see my own mistakes! :)

Comment: +1 for the warning recommendation. (BTW, "`-W -Wall`" is somewhat "deprecated style", nowadays better use "`-Wall -Wextra`", I find)

Answer (score 3):

The function `getInput` says that it returns a `string`, which the calling code attempts to copy. But there is no `return` in your `getInput` function. Since copying a return value that wasn't actually returned is undefined behaviour "anything" could happen at this point - in this case, it would appear that a segfault is the result.

Since you are using `input` as a reference, there is no need to return a string. Just change the function prototype to `void`.

If you enable warnings when compiling, you will see this sort of error more easily.

Answer (score 2):

```
 string getInput(string &input, string prompt)
 {
    cout << prompt;
    getline(cin, input);
 }
```

You declared that the function returns `string` type, but you did not have `return` statement in the function. It will result in undefined behavior when the flow reaches the end of that function.

Try:

```
 void getInput(string &input, string prompt)
 {
    cout << prompt;
    getline(cin, input);
 }
```